# Bulk Insert with Table Valued Parameter with duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Need to insert multiple records into a SQL table. If there are duplicates (already inserted records) then I want to ignore them.

For sending multiple records from my code to SQL, I am using table valued parameter.

I was looking at two options.

Option 1: Make a get call to SQL table and check if there are duplicates and return the duplicate row key. Perform multiple insert with table valued parameter only for those not existing row keys into SQL table.

Option 2: Use table valued parameter and call bulk insert. In the SQL do the duplicate detection and ignore the duplicate rows.

The SQL that was implemented is as follows:

@tvpNewFMdata is the table valued parameter.

```
    INSERT INTO
        [dbo].[FMData]
        (
            [Id],
            [Name],
            [Path],
            [CreatedDate],
            [ModifiedDate]
        )
    SELECT 
        fm.Id, fm.Name, fm.Path, GETUTCDATE(), GETUTCDATE() 
    FROM 
        @tvpNewFMdata AS fm
    WHERE 
        fm.Id NOT IN 
        (
        SELECT 
            [Id] 
        FROM 
            [dbo].[FMdata]
        )
```

In the SQL approach, I do a select first to check whether the row exist and only if does not exist, then I do an insert.

Want to get a better perspective on which approach is performance wise optimized. Also wanted to understand whether the above query is optimized.

Comment: Have you looked at [Merge](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine, although I might make some suggestions.

First, use default values for `CreatedDate` and `ModifiedDate`.  That way, you don't need to set the values every time a row is inserted.

Second, I'm not a fan of `NOT IN`, preferring `NOT EXISTS` instead.  I prefer `NOT EXISTS` because it works more intuitively when the subquery returns `NULL` values.  However, I am guessing that `Id` is a primary key  in `FMData`, so it could never be `NULL`.

Third, `Id` should have an index . . . which it would have as a primary key.

Fourth, the code is not thread safe, meaning that running the same code twice at the same time could generate an error.  I'm guessing this is not a problem for this code, but if so, you can investigate [table locking hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx).

Except for the presence of an index on `Id`, none of these comments address performance.  Your code should be fine from a performance perspective.

Comment: Id is the primary key and so has an index. Regarding the thread safe that would be the case unless i use the right locking hint.